# Delete an object after the callback is called C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I create a new object and set a data and a callback something like this:

```
class DownloadData
{
    std::function<void(int, bool)>    m_callback;
    int                               m_data;
public:
    void sendHttpRequest()
    {
         // send request with data
    }

private:
    void getHttpResponse(int responseCode)
    {
        if (responseCode == 0)
        {
               // save data
               m_callback(responseCode, true);
               delete this;
               return;
        } 

        // some processing here
        if (responseCode == 1 && some other condition here)
        {
               m_callback(responseCode, false);
               delete this;
               return;   
        }
    }
}
```

Now the usage - I create a new object:

```
if (isNeededToDownloadTheFile)
{
    DownloadData* p = new DownloadData(15, [](){});
    p->sendHttpRequest();
}
```

But as you can see https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this it is highly not desirable to make a suicide. Is there a good design pattern or an approach for this?

Comment: Why do you need a pointer here `DownloadData* p`?

Comment: You should look at the "command pattern".

Comment: The problem I see is that a HTTP response may never come. If you have that case handled as well, than having the object manage its own lifetime doesn't seem terrible to me.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Because otherwise the dtor call would sabotage the callback.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if I don't use a `new` then it will be deallocated until the response is back in m_callback will be deleted.

Comment: 2 years later, did you find some better answers (beside the three solutions)?  I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could put them in a `vector` or `list`, have `getHttpResponse()` set a flag instead of `delete this` when it's completed, and then have another part of the code occasionally traverse the list looking for completed requests.

That would also allow you to implement a timeout. If the request hasn't returned in a day, it's probably not going to and you should delete that object.

Comment: Congratulations on implementing a garbage collector.

Comment: Well, it would be simple, work well, and be clear what it's doing. As Ward Cunningham said "Do the simplest thing that could possibly work"..

Comment: Wait, *implementing a garbage collector* and *simple* used together?

Comment: For that sort of limited scope? That's trivial, and it's not a real garbage collector, since there's active communication between the objects and the deleter..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put the delete out of that function, the only way is to store the object somehow. However, this raises the ownership questions: who is the owner of the asynchronous http request that's supposed to call a callback?

In this scenario, doing the GCs job actually makes the code pretty clear. However, if you wanted to make it more adaptable to C++, I'd probably settle on a promise-like interface, similar to `std::async`. That way the synchronous code path makes it way easier to store the promise objects.

You asked for a code example, so there goes:

Typical approach would look like this:

```
{
    DownloadData* p = new DownloadData(15, [](auto data){
        print(data)
    });
    p->sendHttpRequest();
}
```

Once the data is available, it can be printed. However, you can look at the problem "from the other end":

```
{
    Future<MyData> f = DownloadData(15).getFuture();
    // now you can either
    // a) synchronously wait for the future
    // b) return it for further processing
    return f;
}
```

`f` will hold the actual value once the request actually processes. That way you can push it as if it was a regular value all the way up to the place *where that value is actually needed*, and wait for it there. Of course, if you consume it asynchronously, you might as well spawn another asynchronous action for that.

The implementation of the `Future` is something that's outside of the scope of this answer, I think, but then again numerous resources are available online. The concept of Promises and Futures isn't something specific to C++.

Comment: Sorry, you answer does not help me. I still don't know what to do, or what to read to know what to do.

Comment: @Narek it's a simple concept, a bit harder to implement. Instead of passing a callback that will be called when the request ends, [do what this thing does](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) : *run the function f asynchronously (potentially in a separate thread which may be part of a thread pool) and return a std::future that will eventually hold the result of that function call.*

Comment: Code example would be appreciated. I am not familiar with these concepts and I cannot get the grip.

Comment: @Narek I've added some examples and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

If the caller keeps a reference to the downloading object then it can erase it when the download signals it has ended:

```
class DownloadData
{
    // true until download stops (atomic to prevent race)
    std::atomic_bool                  m_downloading;
    int                               m_data;
    std::function<void(int, bool)>    m_callback;

public:
    DownloadData(int data, std::function<void(int, bool)> callback)
    : m_downloading(true), m_data(data), m_callback(callback) {}

    void sendHttpRequest()
    {
         // send request with data
    }

    // called asynchronously to detect dead downloads
    bool ended() const { return !m_downloading; }

private:
    void getHttpResponse(int responseCode)
    {
        if (responseCode == 0)
        {
               // save data
               m_callback(responseCode, true);
               m_downloading = false; // signal end
               return;
        }

        // some processing here
        if(responseCode == 1)
        {
               m_callback(responseCode, false);
               m_downloading = false; // signal end
               return;
        }
    }
};
```

Then from the caller's side:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DownloadData>> downloads;

// ... other code ...

if (isNeededToDownloadTheFile)
{
    // clean current downloads by deleting all those
    // whose download is ended
    downloads.erase(std::remove_if(downloads.begin(), downloads.end(),
    [](std::unique_ptr<DownloadData> const& d)
    {
        return d->ended();
    }), downloads.end());

    // store this away to keep it alive until its download ends
    downloads.push_back(std::make_unique<DownloadData>(15, [](int, bool){}));
    downloads.back()->sendHttpRequest();
}

// ... etc ...
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a very good improvement, but still using the shared pointer's counter looks like a hack. Maybe my `DownloadData` shoud have some flag that says, `isDone` and then you can deallocate it the same we you have done in `if (isNeededToDownloadTheFile)` but at this time by checking the flag and not the ref count.

Comment: @Narek Yes that sounds good, but don't forget the `shared_ptr` reference counting is thread-safe, if you implement your own signal you will have to ensure its synchronized, perhaps by using `std::atomic_bool`. Then you can use `std::unique_ptr` in the vector.

Comment: @Narek Your way is better, so I modified my answer accordingly.